# Spacing components in a Google Apps Script UiApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I create a small UiApp with Google Apps Script.
It uses three CaptionPanels to organise the information presented to the user.
The are packed in right on top of each other. Is there a way to easily space them? I just want a few extra pixel space between the panels.

**Edit:** This works:
`var topPanel = app.createCaptionPanel('My Panel').setStyleAttribute('marginBottom', '5px');`

Based on answer by Bryan P but with correction from [Google Developer Website](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/caption-panel#setStyleAttribute%28String,String%29). The CSS attribute must be in camel-case.

Comment: Have you tried using style attribute padding,10px?

Comment: @Serge insas: Padding adds padding to the inside of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

`var panel1 = app.createCaptionPanel().setStyleAttribute('margin-bottom', '5px')`

Comment: @LaughDonor what link-only answer are you referring to?

Comment: Miscommented. Can you please explain how your code will help solve OP's issue instead of just posting a one-liner.